# Correlation Clustering

Tags: clustering, graph-theory

[Correlation Clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_clustering) : Given a signed graph  where the edge label indicates whether two nodes are similar (+) or different (−), the task is to cluster the vertices so that similar objects are grouped together.

[Papers](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/B%3aMACH.0000033116.57574.95) report that task is NP-Complete and suggest Approximation Algorithms. Can one recommend me a fast-implementation of a naive algorithm to do the task?

Comment: The closely related question at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/ concerns clustering by similar values of the correlations themselves. Although this is not precisely what is being asked here, perhaps it offers some partial help. However, I suspect the present question has been stated ambiguously. As it is, there is an obvious and trivial solution: remove all "-" edges and report the connected components of the graph that remains. This clearly groups the similar objects and is unique; it's definitely not NP-complete. So what *really* is your question?

Answer (score 5):

Here are references for a graph theoretic / social networks approach to clustering:

Guimera , R., Sales-Pardo, M., Amaral, L. (2004). Modularity From Fluctuations In Random Graphs and Complex Networks. *Physical Review E*. 70 (2), 025101

Reichardt, J., and Bornholdt, S. (2006). Statistical Mechanics of Community
     Detection, *Phys. Rev. E*, 74, 016110 (2006), URL:
     http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0603718.

The algorithm is implemented in an R package called `igraph` and is called `spinglass.community()`.

The subfield is often called "community detection," "graph clustering," or "network clustering" and there are many algorithms. This one happens to handle **signed** and **weighted** edges.

The following reference compares many algorithms for efficiency:

Danon, Díaz-Guilera, Duch & Arenas. (2005). Comparing Community Structure Identification. *Journal of Statistical Mechanics: Theory and Experiment*. 2005 (9), P09008.

Comment: To say that the subfield is called community detection is oversimplifying it. In most disciplines the field is simply called 'graph clustering' or 'network clustering'. Refer to my answer here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15824/what-is-the-difference-between-graph-clustering-and-community-detection-methods/60265#60265. Clustering algorithms that one might want to consider additionally (all these have implementations available as well) are DBSCAN, Louvain clustering, RNSC and MCL.

Answer (score 4):

My quick and dirty way to find visualize clusters in graphs is to use the Fruchterman-Reingold force-directed algorithm. The algorithm works as follows:

- take each node, which has weighted (both positive and negative) edges to other nodes, and random toss them on a 2-d plane.
- At each iteration (up to 50 or so), the edges act as *springs* connecting nodes, and there is a calculable force on each node according to the forces acting on it: edges with a high weight attract nodes, and edges with a negative weight repel nodes.

That's it! Nodes eventually start to cluster together. Here's an example I did for a finance project: The nodes are stocks and the edges are correlations.

[image]

You can spot natural clusters, like:

1. center top right are the Financial companies likes GS, BAC, WFC etc.
2. Tech companies are top right: GOOD, AMZN, AAPL
3. Hardware is to the east: NVDA, AMD, ADBE, TXN
4. "Peninsula of Japan" in the south east: MTU, TM, HMC.

here's the code used to generate images likes this:

[github repo](https://github.com/CamDavidsonPilon/Graphical-Lasso-in-Finance)

Answer (score 2):

Here you can find a simple correlation clustering algorithm.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_clustering#Algorithms

Even though the algorithm is very easy to implement, if you want, I can give you the python implementation.

Comment: Isn't the algorithm mentioned an approximation algorithm?

Comment: @damned: Yes it is. Are you looking for a exact solution does not matter exponential?